# Timeit.timeit method. Which way is correct: inner or outer?

Tags: python, timeit

I wanted to check speed of each function, but I ran into a problem. As you can see the code below contains two the same functions: **func & func2**. However, **func was declared directly in timeit.timeit method.** After the test, I have got a result: `Func result: 0.08, func 2 result: 0.21.`. It is a huge difference.

Here is a problem: why identical functions have different speed? Is it the time, that it takes to get func2 from global scope?

```
import timeit


def func2() -> range:
    return range(1024)


def main():
    """
    Number of seconds for each function to perform with 500k executions
    """
    func_res = round(timeit.timeit(
        'def func() -> range: return range(1024); func()',
        number=500_000
        ),
    2)
    func2_res = round(timeit.timeit(
        'func2()',
        number=500_000,
        globals=globals()
        ),
    2)
    return f'Func result: {func_res}, func 2 result: {func2_res}.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

**P.S. 'def func() -> range: return range(1024)' ---> 'def func() -> range: return range(1024); func()' was edited.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two statements you're testing are entirely different.

The first one (`def func() -> range: return range(1024); func()`) only tests how fast Python is at declaring a function with the body `return range(1024); func()`. The second one actually calls the function.

Since `timeit` can also accept a callable, you can just do

```
timeit.timeit(
    func2,
    number=500_000,
)
```

anyway.

Let's try with a better test bench:

```
import timeit


def func2() -> range:
    return range(1024)


def t(name, stmt, setup="pass"):
    res = timeit.timeit(stmt, setup, number=5_000_000, globals=globals()) * 1000
    print(f"{name:>25} {int(res):5d}")


def main():
    t("declare a func", "def func() -> range: return range(1024); func()")
    t("declare & run func", "def func() -> range: return range(1024)\nfunc()")
    t("run local func", "func()", "def func() -> range: return range(1024)")
    t("run global func2 by name", "func2()")
    t("run func2 by ref", func2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can see that the option that declares `func` *and* calls it too is much slower (numbers on my machine, YMMV):

```
           declare a func   547  # <-- doesn't call range!
       declare & run func  1282  # <-- slow...
           run local func   854  # <-- declare function once & call it
 run global func2 by name   836
         run func2 by ref   774
```

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected this, but the result is the same: 0.1 sec vs 0.26 sec!

Comment: Edit your question to include the corrected code and we can take a look.

Comment: @VladMikheenko It was still wrong. See my edit. :)

Comment: Why 'declare a func' does not call range? The string contains a call of function **func**: `t("declare a func", "def func() -> range: return range(1024); func()")`

Comment: @VladMikheenko Because the `;` gets parsed as separating two statements in the function's body.